# Vim highlighting breaks after upgrading from 7.4 to 8.1

Tags: vim, colors, text-editor, color-scheme

I had to update from VIM version 7.4 to 8.1 to make some functions work, but for some reason all highlighting is broken.
I use Ubuntu 18.04 and updated Vim via:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Default color schemes (blue, desert, delek) disappeared. I downloaded few to try, but effect is very strange. For example, this is https://github.com/whatyouhide/vim-gotham
[image]

As you can see, it has some colors (background, numbers, font), but surely not the ones intended.

**UPD:** I found this thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1203649, which has somewhat solution via:

```
:source /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/sh.vim
```

In the provided thread, issue was connected with manual setting for runtimepath. But the provided solution doesn't work for me

Comment: `Default color schemes (blue, desert, delek) disappeared` It has something to do with Ubuntu packaging. Normally Vim 8 includes all these schemes.

Is it ony vim or gvim or both? Have you tried to use `set termguicolors`?

Comment: Both vim and gvim. Also, please, check question update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to solve the issue. Apparently it has something to do with upgrading existing vim under Ubuntu.
I added the following lines to explicitly set correct rtp:

`set rtp=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vim81`

And it worked.